# restkit and three20

Tags: three20, restkit

I couldn't find a lot of good documentation on three20, so my question is what if any is the overlap between restkit and three20 in the url cache and request methods. Does it make sense to use three20's TTURLRequest with RestKit?

Are they complementary or overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read this tutorial about [Restkit][1]

[1]: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/advanced-restkit-development_iphone-sdk/, and here is the section

> **Three20 Support At Two Toasters**, the vast majority of our iOS
>   applications are built on top of two frameworks: RestKit and Three20.
>   We have found that Three20 greatly simplifies and streamlines a number
>   of common patterns in our iOS applications (such as the support for
>   URL based dispatch) and provides a rich library of UI components and
>   helpers that make us happier, more productive programmers. And RestKit
>   obviously makes working with data so much more pleasant. So it should
>   come as little surprise that there integration points available
>   between the two frameworks. **Integration between RestKit and Three20
>   takes the form of an implementation of the TTModel protocol**. TTModel
>   defines an interface for abstract data models to inform the Three20
>   user interface components of their status and provide them with data.
>   TTModel is the basis for all Three20 table view controllers as well as
>   a number of other components. RestKit ships with an optional
>   libRestKitThree20 target that provides an interface for driving
>   Three20 table views off of a RestKit object loader via the
>   RKRequestTTModel class. RKRequestTTModel allows us to handle all the
>   modeling, parsing, and object mapping with RestKit and then plug our
>   data model directly into Three20 for presentation. RKRequestTTModel
>   also provides transparent offline support and periodic data refresh in
>   our user interfaces. When you have used Core Data to back your data
>   model and utilize RKRequestTTModel in your controllers, RestKit will
>   automatically pull any objects from the cache that live at the
>   resource path you are loading in the event you are offline.
>   RKRequestTTModel can also be configured to hit the network only after
>   a certain amount of time by configuring the refreshRate property. In
>   addition to RKRequestTTModel, a child class RKRequestFilterableTTModel
>   is provided as well. RKRequestFilterableTTModel provides support for
>   sorting and searching a collection of loaded objects and can be useful
>   for providing client side filtering operations.